# Passing by reference to a constructor

Tags: c++, constructor, pass-by-reference

I decided to see if assigning a reference to a member would make a member a reference. I wrote the following snippet to test it. There's a simple class `Wrapper` with an `std::string` as a member variable. I take take a `const string&` in the constructor and assign it to the public member variable. Later in the `main()` method I modify the member variable but the `string` I passed to the constructor remains unchanged, how come? I think in Java the variable would have changed, why not in this code snippet? How exactly do references work in this case?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

class Wrapper
{
public:
   string str;

   Wrapper(const string& newStr)
   {
      str = newStr;
   }
};

int main (int argc, char * const argv[]) 
{
   string str = "hello";
   cout << str << endl;
   Wrapper wrapper(str);
   wrapper.str[0] = 'j'; // should change 'hello' to 'jello'
   cout << str << endl;
}
```

Comment: Types in C++ are what you decree, and they don't magically become something else. You say `string`, and you get a `string`. If you wanted a reference, you'd have said `string &`.

Comment: You abused people with too simple question :)

Comment: In Java the variable wouldn't have changed because the code wouldn't even have compiled; strings in Java aren't allowed to be modified.

Answer (score 51, accepted):

To assign a reference in a constructor you need to have a reference member

```
 class A{
     std::string& str;
 public:
     A(std::string& str_)
     :    str(str_) {} 
 };
```

str is now a reference to the value you passed in. Same applies for const refs

```
 class A{
     const std::string& str;
 public:
     A(const std::string& str_)
     :    str(str_) {} 
 };
```

However don't forget that once a reference has been assigned it can not be changed so if assignment requires a change to str then it will have to be a pointer instead.

Comment: Interesting to know that having references as data members is something to avoid: https://herbsutter.com/2020/02/23/references-simply/

Answer (score 13):

Because `Wrapper::str` is not a reference, it's an independent object.  So when you do `str = newStr`, you're *copying* the string.

Answer (score 6):

```
class Wrapper
{
public:
   string& str;

   Wrapper(string& newStr) : str(newStr) {}
};
```

Note, you cannot accept a `const string&` and store it in a `string&`, you would lose const-correctness in doing so.

Answer (score 5):

You need to use an initializer and declare `str` as a reference as in:

```
class Wrapper {
public:
   string &str;

   Wrapper(string& newStr)
      : str(newStr) {
   }
};
```

The way you're writing it, all you are doing is copying the value of the reference you pass to the constuctor.  You're not saving the reference.  By declaring a reference as a class member and initializing it with a reference to another string instance, you will get the behavior you're looking for.

Comment: Your code tries to initialize a reference-to-mutable with a reference-to-const.

Comment: Fixed... that's what I get for blindly copying from the OP.

Answer (score 1):

You should declare `Wrapper::str` as a `string&`, not as a `string`.

Answer (score 1):

Your main body variable is `std::string`.

Your parameter variable is `const std::string&`.

The const in references are always "low level const", meaning it modifies the type of object not the actual object.

In contrast a "top level const" modifies an actual object. Read [C++ Primer on Top level const](https://www.safaribooksonline.com/library/view/c-primer-fifth/9780133053043/ch02lev2sec15.html) for clarification.

Here is how your assignment looks like when you pass arguments:

```
const std::string& = std::str; //Values are ommited
// i.e const std::string newStr = std::string str
```

You are initializing a **`const type reference`** with a **`non-const value`** which is acceptable. You are not supposed to change the value of `std::string str` using that reference. And, if you try changing the value of `newStr` inside the constructor, you *will get a compilation error*.

Next you're doing another assignment inside the constructor which is also acceptable:

```
std::string = const std::string
```

The fact that `wrap.str[0]` didn't change `str` of `main` is that, although a reference was used to instantiate `class str`, `class str` has its own object and is not linked to `main str`. Using that reference in a parameter just links that parameter to `main str`; not `main str` to `class str`.

If your class variables were referenced, then it could have changed.