# Initializing a reference member: reason for different syntax

Tags: c++, constructor, reference, initialization

I have two classes, with one on them having an object of the other as reference Member:

```
class myClass{
public:
    myClass() { };
};

class mySecondClass {
public:
    mySecondClass(myClass& reference)
    {
        myClassReference = reference; //doesn't get accepted by the compiler
    };

    myClass& myObjectReference;
};
```

I found out (thanks to [Passing by reference to a constructor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9507008/passing-by-reference-to-a-constructor)
), that `mySecondClass(myClass& reference) : myObjectReference(reference){};` does the job.

But why can't I use `myObjectReference = reference;`?

Comment: I want to add that I am quite new to C++ and am not always able to understand the c++ reference sites (which might make this question searchable)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's because `{ myClassReference = reference; }` is considered as an
assignment to something which is supposed to be already initialised.

The member initialisation list `: member1{value1}, member2{value2}...`
is intended to provide the initial value (nothing is supposed to
be valid before).

For the specific case of a reference, it's the same situation as

```
int i=4;
int &r=i; // the reference is initialised (alias for i)
r=5;      // the reference itself is not changed but
          //   the referenced object (i) is assigned
```

Comment: So the compiler basicly thinks I want to change the variable the reference is pointing to?

Comment: @SebastianDonnerWolfBach yes exactly, and by the way, in your proposition, the reference is not explicitly initialised to point to something

Answer (score 2):

In the constructor

```
mySecondClass(myClass& reference)
{
    myClassReference = reference; //doesn't get accepted by the compiler
};
```

there is used reference `myClassReference` that shall be initialized when it is created.  However the variable was not initialized. There is used the copy assignment operator.

In this constructor

```
mySecondClass(myClass& reference) : myObjectReference(reference){}
                                    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

the reference is created and initialized in the mem-initializer list.

To make it more clear consider the following demonstrative program.

```
#include <iostream>

struct Int
{
    Int() { std::cout << "Int()\n"; }
    Int( int x ) : x( x ) { std::cout << "Int( " << x << " )\n"; }
    Int & operator =( int x )
    {
        std::cout << "Int & operator =( " << x << " )\n";
        this->x = x;

        return *this;
    }

    int x;
};

struct A
{
    A( int x )
    {
        this->value = x;
    }
    Int value;
};

struct B
{
    B( int x ) : value( x ) {}
    Int value;
};

int main() 
{
    A a( 10 );

    std::cout << '\n';

    B b( 10 );

    return 0;
}
```

Its output is

```
Int()
Int & operator =( 10 )

Int( 10 )
```

That is when the body of the constructor A gets the control the data member was already created using the default constructor of the class Int. Within the body of the constructor there is used the assignment operator.

Opposite to the constructor of the class A the constructor of the class B created the data member in the mem-inkitializer list using the constructor of the class Int with a parameter.

So now imagine that you are using a reference in the class A. Then it is "default-initialized" that is it is not actually initialized by any valid object to which it shell refer. So in the body of the constructor you are trying to assign a value to an invalid reference that refers nowhere. So the compiler issues an error.